# Prioritize jar file over source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project in eclipse 3.2.1

I have a java class `com.abc.Dinesh` in source.
And I also have a some jar file that has a class with the same name and package.

I imported the jar file in my project.  However, in my source code when I'm referencing class Dinesh, the class is resolved to the source and not the binary version.  I want to refer to the class file in from the jar.

How can I do this?

~Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to remove that source file from your project?  Or at least remove it from the build path of your project?  If it is in your jar file it seems you would not need it in your project.

Comment: But if I compile and export jar file then the class will not be present in Jar file. All I want to set the priority in eclipse i.e; pick the class from source or this particular jar file. 

We do this while setting classpath externally in application, the jar file loaded first is taken first.

Comment: or suppose there are 2 jar files A.jar and B.jar and both have same file com.abc.Dinesh; The jar file loaded first will be used. So my question how to set such class-path or prioritize jars, source code in eclipse.

Comment: This is not just in eclipse, in case of running project if lib folder having two different jars having same package structure then whatever is loaded fist will be consider first. And I think this sequence can not be monitor/define any place.

Comment: And this kind of issue arise in case of backup of existing jar and upload of new jar on server. Consider we have xyz.jar and if I update my code build up a new jar. Obviously I will write same name for that newly bild jar. So previous jar should be bkup with some other extention like xyz_current_date_time.jar.bkup so that older jar will not be loaded.

Comment: The sequnce can be defined by setting classpath in order or in case of tomcat rename the jar So that the jar is picked up in sorted manner; first like rename the jar with a.jar . So it will be loaded before b.jar

or consider using OSGI model . I can define which jar and which version. But all i want to know is how can it be done in eclipse.

Comment: are you talking about two jars or one jar and the other as src .java ?

Comment: "I have a java class com.abc.Dinesh in source. " is that in the same project or different project?

Comment: Src is source code... and other one is jar which is imported in eclipse project.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following:

```
right click on your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path...
```

Then go to the tab

```
Order and Export
```

Select (simple click) your jar and press `Top` or just `Up` until it is above the `src` entry.

Comment: I tried order and export in  eclipe 3.2.1 but it only changes the view in project explorer,it actually does not set the priority of classpath.

Comment: @108 it works, at least on my Juno version of eclipse, i'll try to get a 3.2.1 an d test it on it too, if it doesn't then it is a bug in eclipse. but before saying that try to run `java` with the option `-verbose` to see witch classes are loaded from where.

Comment: @108 3.2.1 is not compatible with my os (win7) so i tested it using the oldest one compatible with it -> [eclipse version 3.3](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/) and it works just fine. Also i suggest you get [the latest version of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) since [3.2.1](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.php) is way too old. Personally i doubt that this a problem with eclipse.

Comment: i guess even if it ups that jar priority it wont up it relative to .java files.

Comment: @tgkprog i guess you might want to test it like i did: Create project in eclipse with two classes `Test.java` with a method witch prints the text `From Jar` and `Main.java` witch instanciates an object of `Test` and calls its method. Now export the project as jar file and add that jar to the class path. Change the print method to write `From Src` and execute the main class, `From Src` is printed, Now follow the steps in the answer and move the jar to  the top. rerun the main class, now what is printed ?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to resolve your problem (within or outside Eclipse) is to code you own ClassLoader to prioritize Jar files over class files. :

see http://kalanir.blogspot.fr/2010/01/how-to-write-custom-class-loader-to.html

And then setting the jvm "java.system.class.loader" property with the new one

Answer (score 1):

Workaround : Do not refer to the .java files. Remove the .java file / move it to a different project? and do not refer to that project in this, only to the jar, either directly or to a copy of the version you want in your lib

Comment: But if I compile and export jar file then the class will not be present in Jar file.

Comment: is that not what you want ? for your project to refer to a jar and not the latest source file?

Comment: I want to Prioritize the location from where to load classes, I don't want to exclude any .java file.

Comment: well i think that goes beyond the capabilities of eclipse. no idea. maybe you can ask this in the eclipse forums

Answer (score 1):

The load order of classloaders is Bootstrap CL-->System CL-->Extended CL

Now the jar & your source files are in System CL. Move the JAR file to ext folder in you JDK. That way you give precedence to classes on system classpath over jars.

Comment: But would that be a right way to do.. ? I mean I will add my thirdparty jars to JRE ext folder

Comment: Well, you are anyway trying to mess up with classloaders of Eclipse.Do it the cleaner way which i've suggested. You dont wanna get involved in CL issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two class with same name in classpath in different packages. In this case if you are using both the class in same code you will need to qualify with its package. e.g. to reference `Dinesh` you will need to do something like

```
com.abc.Dinesh dinesh = new com.abc.Dinesh();
```

Comment: I agree that namespacing is the way forward, but it seems that the packages are the same.  

The question says "I also have a some jar file that has a class with the same name and package."